# Recognizing spaces as part of a python path

Tags: python-3.x, path, jupyter-notebook

I am attempting to create a "path2data" variable which points to a path containing spaces. Unfortunately I am unable to modify the path itself to get rid of spaces, and am curious if anyone might have gotten this to work.

Code:

```
    path2data = '/Users/main/Dropbox\ (Enterprise\ Data\)/Practice/BData_Practice/'

cort = pd.read_excel(path2data + "Python_Self_Report_Data.ipynb.xlsx", sheet_name='MASQ')
```

Error: FileNotFoundError

Comment: You could try `path2data = r'/Users/main/Dropbox (Enterprise Data)/Practice/BData_Practice/'`

Comment: First, you should change the '\' to '/'

Comment: thank you! replacing the '\' to /' works well.